# c++- print all nodes in a queue

Tags: c++

How do I print the all the nodes that is inside my queue?

I tried to do this but it's returning me address pointers.

```
    #include <queue>
    struct node
    {
        int weight;
        int value;
        float bound;
    }  

    std::queue<node> q;
    node n;

    q.push(n);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        n = q.front();
        std::cout << &n << std::endl;
        q.pop();
    }
```

Comment: `cout << &n` says to print the address of `n`, so it makes sense that that's what's happening. If you want to print the contents of a `node`, you should `cout` `n.weight`, `n.value`, and `n.bound` (with whatever formatting makes sense).

Comment: "it's returning me address pointers." That's because you're *requesting* addresses (remove the ampersand if you don't want the pointer).

Comment: Can you print single `node` objects?

Comment: oh ya.almost forgot about it. thanks

Comment: Also note, your q will be empty after the loop. Usually not what one wants when just printing the elements.

Answer (score 5):

You *are* printing the addresses, using the "address-of" operator:

```
std::cout << &n << std::endl;
```

I suspect you inserted the "&" to stop the compiler from complaining that there's no `<<` operator for `node`.
It's much more effective to provide one:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const node& n)
{
     // Output the data from 'n' on 'os' the way you like...
     os << "whatever";
     return os;
}
```

Comment: +1 for reverse compiling thought processes to determine where & came from!

Answer (score -1):

```
std::cout << n.member_variables << std::endl;
```

How about this?

Comment: Pretty sure that won't compile, seeing how there is no `operator<<` for node.